# 2 tables select not showing correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I just trying to select from 2 tables but I got stuck.

**Table 1 - partners**

```
picture | name | department | company | country | partners_id
--------------------------------------------------------------
img.jpg | John | Developer  | XYZ     | Germany | 140266157291
img.jpg | John | Developer  | XYZ     | Germany | 540266157295
```

**Table 2 - Partners_social**

```
social_img  |  social_url  |  assign_id  | 
----------------------------------------- 
soc_img.jpg | www.link.com | 140266157291|
soc_img.jpg | www.link.com | 140266157291|
soc_img.jpg | www.link.com | 540266157295|
```

**index**

```
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `partners` ORDER BY `ID` DESC") or die(mysql_error());
    while($part = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $id = $part['partners_id']; 

         echo'      
        <div class="team"  style="margin-top:20px;">
<div class="left_team"><img src="./admin/images/team/'.$part['picture'].'" class="team_img_circle"  style="border:1px solid #c9c9c9;"></div>
<div class="right_team">
<span><img src="./admin/images/flags/'.$part['flag'].'.png" width="18" height="18" ></span><br>
<span style="font-size:16px; color:#e5007d;">'.$part['department'].'</span><br>
<span style="font-size:22px; color:#000; font-weight:bold;">'.$part['name'].'</span><br>
<span style="font-size:16px; color:#000;">'.$part['company'].'</span><br><br>
 <span class="social_team">
'; 
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `partners_social` WHERE `assign_id`= '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
    while($part_soc = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){    
        if($part_soc['social_url'] == NULL){}
        else{echo '<a href="'.$part_soc['social_url'].'"><img src="./admin/images/social/'.$part_soc['social_img'].'.png"></a>';}
}
echo'  
</span>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
';
}
```

I am trying to select 2 tables where second table has same assign_id like partners_id. If I am doing it without that second query working fine showing me both of partners from **Table1** on site. But if I trying it with that second query always showing me just one partner from **table1**. Some solution for that ? I am was thinking about something like **foreach()** but not sure.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is inside the first loop you are using

```
$query = mysql_query
```

And the first query is also using the same

```
$query = mysql_query
```

So inside the first loop its getting over written and the first loop executed only once.

TO fix this , give a different variable name for the 2nd query something as

```
$query1 = mysql_query
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting $query in your while. On the next round it points to the wrong statement.

You should not do this at all, however. You should use a join in the first query and get all information in one statement.